# How to find input to Gamma CDF which gives specific probability

Tags: probability, distributions, random-variable, gamma-distribution

I would like a formula which allows me to input some value for a Gamma distribution random variable, and get back the total probability density up to that point.

In essence, I would like say, a value of 0.05, or 0.95 returned from the Gamma CDF.

How do I know what value for the random variable would give this? It appears non-trivial due to the Gamma function itself. Is there actually a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not analytically available. You can use numerical approaches/software. What you want to find is actually inverse CDF of [quantile function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_function) in other words.

In `Matlab` you can use [`gaminv`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/gaminv.html), in `R`, you can use [`qgamma`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/GammaDist.html), or in `python` you can use [`ppf`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gamma.html) in `scipy.stats`.

It's not easy to find a table but here is [one](http://www.nrcc.cornell.edu/services/research/reports/RR_91-2.pdf) with unit scale, with varying shape parameters (upto some limit of course). Unfortunately, it's not as easy as for standard normal, i.e. Z table. You can use [scaling property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution#/Scaling) of Gamma to convert Gamma's with different scales.

Comment: There are *two* definitions of standard Gammas and one is extensively tabulated: it's called the chi-squared distribution.